# How can I create a backup of an instance in Amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have some 8 instances in Amazon. Could someone tell me how I can create a backup/image of a running instance?

I have already gone through their database. But I could not understand it. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes just need to take snapshots, Goto EC2,

Select volumes. Select the volume you want to take backup and then take snapshot.

You may export them to s3 even, if needed

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the  reply. I could find the option to Create a snapshot when I select the volume. But I am not sure as to which volume to select. How can I relate a particular volume and an instance?